# Signal when PulseAudio load/unload modules

Tags: pulseaudio, c++, c, dbus

There is a way to know if PulseAudio has loaded/unloaded a module? Like a signal from PulseAudio?

I know how to query for modules:

```
pactl list sinks
```

but I need some sort of IPC signal mechanism from PulseAudio to my C/C++ application.

I'm aware of the existence of D-Bus for PulseAudio, but the methods there are completely useless...

Maybe there is a file in which PulseAudio saves the list of modules and I can attach a watch to it?

Some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not going directly to PulseAudio development library. I expect `pa_context_set_subscribe_callback()` and may be such `PA_SUBSCRIPTION_MASK_MODULE` mask.[Reference](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/def_8h.html#ad4e7f11f879e8c77ae5289145ecf6947a3d8796f69287b74efd0471977eb4b30c).